# How to find most similar numerical arrays to one array, using Numpy/Scipy?

Tags: numpy, vector, scipy

Let's say I have a list of 5 words:

```
[this, is, a, short, list]
```

Furthermore, I can classify some text by counting the occurrences of the words from the list above and representing these counts as a vector:

```
N = [1,0,2,5,10] # 1x this, 0x is, 2x a, 5x short, 10x list found in the given text
```

In the same way, I classify many other texts (count the 5 words per text, and represent them as counts - each row represents a different text which we will be comparing to N):

```
M = [[1,0,2,0,5],
     [0,0,0,0,0],
     [2,0,0,0,20],
     [4,0,8,20,40],
     ...]
```

Now, I want to find the top 1 (2, 3 etc) rows from M that are most similar to N. Or on simple words, the most similar texts to my initial text.

The challenge is, just checking the distances between N and each row from M is not enough, since for example row M4 [4,0,8,20,40] is very different by distance from N, but still proportional (by a factor of 4) and therefore very similar. For example, the text in row M4 can be just 4x as long as the text represented by N, so naturally all counts will be 4x as high.

What is the best approach to solve this problem (of finding the most 1,2,3 etc similar texts from M to the text in N)?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Generally speaking, the most widely standard technique of bag of words (i.e. you arrays) for similarity is to check cosine similarity measure. This maps your bag of `n` (here 5) words to a `n`-dimensional space and each array is a point (which is essentially also a point vector) in that space. The most similar vectors(/points) would be ones that have the least angle to your text `N` in that space (this automatically takes care of proportional ones as they would be close in angle). Therefore, here is a code for it (assuming `M` and `N` are numpy arrays of the similar shape introduced in the question):

```
import numpy as np
cos_sim = M[np.argmax(np.dot(N, M.T)/(np.linalg.norm(M)*np.linalg.norm(N)))]
```

which gives output `[ 4  0  8 20 40]` for your inputs.

Comment: If you want to efficiently compare distances between all vectors, not just one, consider scipy's [`pdist`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/generated/scipy.spatial.distance.pdist.html), like `pdist(M, 'cosine')`

Comment: @stevemoThank you for the suggestion. `pdist` measures distances among observations in 1 matrix. However, here we want distance between `N` and `M`. Stacking them and using `pdist` is not efficient considering we do not care about distances among `M`  (or `N`). numpy solution is also generalizable to more multiple texts.

Comment: Yes, I understood the OPs question - I was just adding to your perfectly acceptable answer in case someone comes here wanting to find a distance mat instead of one pair wise comp, which is a little unusual.

Comment: @stevemo Good idea. Thank you for the add on.

Answer (score 1):

You can normalise your row counts to remove the length effect as you discussed. Row normalisation of `M` can be done as `M / M.sum(axis=1)[:, np.newaxis]`. The residual values can then be calculated as the sum of the square difference between `N` and `M` per row. The minimum difference (ignoring `NaN` or `inf` values obtained if the row sum is 0) is then the most similar.

Here is an example:

```
import numpy as np

N = np.array([1,0,2,5,10])
M = np.array([[1,0,2,0,5],
              [0,0,0,0,0],
              [2,0,0,0,20],
              [4,0,8,20,40]])

# sqrt of sum of normalised square differences
similarity = np.sqrt(np.sum((M / M.sum(axis=1)[:, np.newaxis] - N / np.sum(N))**2, axis=1))
# remove any Nan values obtained by dividing by 0 by making them larger than one element
similarity[np.isnan(similarity)] = similarity[0]+1

result = M[similarity.argmin()]

result
>>> array([ 4,  0,  8, 20, 40])
```

You could then use `np.argsort(similarity)[:n]` to get the `n` most similar rows.